# Django RegexField to validate a 6-digit number

Tags: regex, django, django-forms

I'm having a heck of a time validating a 6-digit number:

```
# forms.py
class TheForm(forms.Form):
    code = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\d{6}$')

# tests.py
class TheFormTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_the_form(self):
        form = TheForm(initial={'code': '123456'})
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid(),
            'Form should accept a string of 6 characters '
            'that are digits')
```

My test case is returning invalid. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Test it using `form = TheForm(data={'code': '123456'})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial):

> initial values are not used as "fallback" data in validation if a
>   particular field's value is not given. initial values are only
>   intended for initial form display

You should use `data` argument:

```
form = TheForm(data={'code': '123456'})
```

Comment: Jeebus. I can't believe I overlooked that, as long as I've been working with Django. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Initial  data isn't used for validation. You should pass the `data` parameter.